# Is it possible to update libicu on Centos 7?

Tags: centos

The current version of `libicu` is 57, but on CentOS 7 it's locked to version 50.

I've tried various third-party repos such as [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), [remi](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/) and [IUS](https://ius.io/), but none of them seems to provide an updated package for this OS.

How can I update `libicu` to a newer version on CentOS 7?

Comment: You could start a software depot somewhere else with the necessary libs, e.g. under `/opt` (but then you're responsible for the security updates there).

Comment: Did you check EPEL?

Comment: @thrig That's way outside of my comfort zone, I'm looking for a turnkey package, or else I'll probably be better off switching to another OS such as Fedora, that comes with more up-to-date packages.

Comment: Well, that is rather the point of CentOS - it's supposed to be analogous to Red Hat, which by design is slower to incorporate newer packages due in part to ensuring that there are no changes to the APIs of the available software stacks.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I've tried `EPEL` as well, which is a requirement for `remi`. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I'm aware of that, I was just hoping that individual packages could be updated on an as-needed basis, thanks mainly to 3rd party repositories. This is the case for many packages (for example I get the very latest PHP versions thanks to the `remi` repository), but not for all of them as far as I can see.

Comment: Updating libraries in CentOS can be complicated, since other packages build against those libraries.  That said, IUS has a process for requesting new packages: https://ius.io/Contributing/#new-package-request